# Axapta Business Connector

Tags: c++, com, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, business-connector

As we know that COM Business Connector provides Microsoft COM interoperability, we used COM Business Connector to interact with Microsoft COM before Axapta 4.0. In Axapta 2012, COM Business Connector is no longer supported,  but for the .NET Business Connector. The problem is that our Microsoft COM was programmed with C++.

So is there anyone know how to interact with Axapta 2012 in my C++ COM?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to interact with AX 2012 is to use the WCF services that AX 2012 exposes. You can expose existing services or you can create your own. The .NET business connector might be supported at the moment, but I'm pretty sure I won't be in the next iteration of AX.

I have no experience with C++ and/or COM so I'm not sure how you would do that, but if it's possible, it's the way to go.